# Golang for select loop consumes 100% of cpu

Tags: go, cpu

I have a resource that needs to be loaded before any access is allowed to it. It also needs to be updated every minute.

The channels are of length 1 struct{}, so the loop will be blocked if the resource has not been loaded.

This code below started to use 100% of my cpu, I tried adding

```
time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
```

Which made the application cpu consumption drop to 1%

I am thinking a ticker would be a better option for the timed collection.

Any ideas why it would consume 100% cpu or any better ideas for implemention?

```
func (al *AsyncLoop) Run() {
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-al.chanFetchRequest:
                if al.fetched == false {
                    al.fetchData()
                } else if al.lastUpdated.Add(1*time.Minute).Unix() < time.Now().Unix() && al.fetching == false {
                    go al.fetchData()
                }
                al.chanFetchResponse <- struct{}{}
                continue
            default:
                continue
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: You have a default case in your select, meaning that the for loop will spin if there is nothing to read from `al.al.chanFetchRequest`.

Comment: Also looking at how `al.lastUpdated`, `scp.fetching` and `go al.fetchData()` there is also a chance you have data race in this code as well.

Comment: Yes thanks for spotting that, I will add some get and set methods with a mutex

Answer (score 4):

`default` statement creates a nonblocking infinite loop that leads 100% cpu usage. When the condition for case is not satisfied, the loop goes to the default nonblocking infinite loop.

Removing `default` will resolve the issue. But there will be a linter warning `S1000: should use for range instead of for { select {} }` to inform that `select` is meaningless with single channel.

The final code will be

```
for {
    _ := <-al.chanFetchRequest
    if al.fetched == false {
        al.fetchData()
        nextFetch = time.Now().Add(1 * time.Minute)
    } else if time.Now().After(nextFetch) {
        al.fetchData()
        nextFetch = time.Now().Add(1 * time.Minute)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just post to al.chanFetchRequest when there is new data so I think you have to keep reading from this channel all the time.  Adding a ticker to the select might cause you to fetch the data even if it has not changed or (worse) before it has even loaded. Why not, in the normal case, take the time whenever you fetch the data then the next time make sure you have waited enough time before fetching again.  Something like this:

```
        var nextFetch time.Time
        for {
            select {
            case <-al.chanFetchRequest:
                if al.fetched == false {
                    al.fetchData()
                    nextFetch = time.Now().Add(1 * time.Minute)
                } else if time.Now().After(nextFetch) {
                    al.fetchData()
                    nextFetch = time.Now().Add(1 * time.Minute)
                }
                al.chanFetchResponse <- struct{}{}
            }
        }
```

Comment: A select with a single case has no purpose. Just read from the channel.

Comment: @Adrian thanks - you are right which is exactly what I said in my 2nd answer (below). However, it could be useful if you think you will add other cases later.